# Why isn't the CSS working in Google Chrome on my site that uses bootstrap? IS @font-face the Issue maybe?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, google-chrome, font-face

For some reason chrome is not supporting changes to make the background white and a change from one custom font to another custom font.

I am wondering why isn't the CSS working in Google Chrome on my website that is using bootstrap? @font-face the Issue?

```
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "teletype", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #000;
}
.btn {
    background-color: #595959;
    font-size: 45px;
}
.dropdown {
    background-color: #595959;
    font-size: 45px;
    height: 70px;
}
.sidenav {
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #595959;
    height: 100%;
}
.well {
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #595959;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    border-color: #fff;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(fonts/teletype.ttf);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a caching thing - try pressing `Ctrl` and `F5` at the same time to force a full refresh.

Comment: @LukeBriggs is that the same as command + r on a mac?  It seems to be working on chrome now... but I swear i refreshed it a bunch on chrome before

Comment: Nope; on macOS it's `Shift+Command+R` - this is a forced refresh where it skips the cache, unlike a regular refresh (just `Command+R`/ just `F5` on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

ohhh...
i think you are missing something, i do some font-face too like yours.

you missing quote.

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'PapaYeah';
    src:url(../assets/font/yeah-papa/subir/YeahPapa.ttf) format('truetype');
    }
```

this kind of quote `'`